# Laravel and express (node)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, express

I am learning express and have worked in laravel, I feel both following same traditions, like routing in both cases, even use of names like "request", "app", the RESTfull structure.
I had feeling that one is following the other one, is it so? Are they motivated/inspired by each other. Different languages but kind of similar way of implementations.

Comment: Laravel was inspired by Rails

Comment: Express is Sinatra-inspired